# Same docker image works on one machine and fails on the other

Tags: docker

I have two machines running docker 1.13. I try to run a centos:7 image with the following command:

```
docker run -it centos:7
```

On machine A the container starts and shows me the prompt as I'm inside the centos container now. However on machine B when running the same image I get:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory".
```

There seems to be something wrong with my docker setup I presume although the default hello-world image does run and also ubuntu for example works. Any idea what could be the problem or how I can debug this?

Below is the docker info of both machines:

Machine A (the working one):

```
Containers: 3
 Running: 2
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 21
Server Version: 1.13.0
Storage Driver: btrfs
 Build Version: Btrfs v4.2.2
 Library Version: 101
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins: 
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 03e5862ec0d8d3b3f750e19fca3ee367e13c090e
runc version: 2f7393a47307a16f8cee44a37b262e8b81021e3e
init version: 949e6fa
Kernel Version: 4.1.12-61.1.23.el6uek.x86_64
Operating System: Oracle Linux Server 6.8
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 5.577 GiB
Name: lnx70347
ID: WNMG:SW3H:FLZE:CP7Z:UQ6H:XUOA:ZCVA:SUEH:LBWG:J43W:XJNW:LYUX
Docker Root Dir: /env/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Machine B:

```
Containers: 44
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 44
Images: 29
Server Version: 1.13.0
Storage Driver: btrfs
 Build Version: Btrfs v4.2.2
 Library Version: 101
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins: 
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 03e5862ec0d8d3b3f750e19fca3ee367e13c090e
runc version: 2f7393a47307a16f8cee44a37b262e8b81021e3e
init version: 949e6fa
Kernel Version: 4.1.12-61.1.23.el6uek.x86_64
Operating System: Oracle Linux Server 6.8
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 5.577 GiB
Name: lnx70346
ID: 3ZM2:CINA:5GBI:U63B:RWBM:QS5T:XD2P:6YPV:HQRF:VY3P:7OYC:4TJJ
Docker Root Dir: /docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Comment: What happens if you run `docker pull centos:7` on machine B?

Comment: BMitch, then it will state that the image is already present. If I delete it using docker rmi and try another pull, it will download the image as it should

Comment: After pulling a new copy of the image to machine B, does the error still occur? Does `docker inspect centos:7` differ between the two machines? As a last resort, I'd consider /var/lib/docker corrupt, stop docker and give it a wipe, you'll lose all downloaded images, containers, and volumes.

Comment: BMitch, your suggestion to remove everything from /var/lib/docker was the right one. I removed everything and restarted docker. Now it works as it should. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, it appears you had some kind of corruption in the docker filesystem. You may have been able to remove and pull the image again, but the last resort of stopping the docker service and wiping /var/lib/docker will return the system to a clean state. This will remove not only any downloaded images, but also any containers and volumes, so be sure to backup any data you have stored in docker prior to doing this.

Comment: I had an insidious problem with some containers working fine and others not on some system. Wiping using `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker/*` with priorly applying the commands in https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-remove-docker-images-containers-and-volumes fixed the problem. Maybe I should not have used `docker rm --force` so much on that machine?

Comment: @masterxilo If something has been corrupted, I'd just wipe the `/var/lib/docker` directory rather than running docker commands to clean it up. The docker commands assume the filesystem is not corrupt.